# Endpoints of intrinsic diameter of a convex polyhedron

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, polyhedra

Let $P$ be a convex polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $d(P)$ its intrinsic diameter,
i.e., the longest shortest surface path between two points. Say that $P$ is of
class

- $D_0$ if neither endpoint of $d(P)$ is a vertex.
- $D_1$ if one endpoint is a vertex and the other not.
- $D_2$ if both endpoints are vertices.

(I believe these classes are mutually exclusive but I haven't proven that.)

My question is:

> ***Q***. In the space $\mathcal{P}_n$ of all convex polyhedra on $n$ vertices,
> what proportion are of class $D_0, D_1, D_2$ ?

My intuition is that polyhedra of class $D_0$ are rare, whereas
"most" polyhedra are of class $D_1$.
Even approximate relative proportions would be useful.

Comment: What is the measure on the space of convex polyhedra with $n$ vertices? By default I assume that the $3n$ coordinates all have independent standard normal distributions, and we look at the subspace corresponding to convex polyhedra.

Comment: Can you give an easy example in class $D_0$?

Comment: @MattF. For a tall triangular prism, the centroids of the base and top determine the diameter. I have an image in one of my papers but I cannot access it at the moment.

Comment: @MattF. This is how the space is typically handled. "Consider the space $S$ of all convex surfaces, endowed with the topology induced by the usual Pompeiu-Hausdorff metric. Fix some $P \in S$. Consider in $S$ the subset $\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{P}^n_P$ of all polyhedra $Q \subset P$ with precisely $n$ vertices, with the induced topology. Two polyhedra in $P$ are then close to each other if and only if they have close corresponding vertices."

Comment: That puts the polyhedra in a metric space, but how do we get the probability measure? The Hausdorff measure on its subspace of convex polyhedra with unit surface area is available, but that seems complicated.

Comment: @MattF. I don't know how to make this precise. I'll have to study the work of Zamfirescu, e.g., "This paper completes the description of the curvature
behaviour of most convex surfaces, the words "most" and "typical" being
used in the sense of "all, except those in a set of first Baire category".  ("Curvature properties of typical convex surfaces"). I would be happy with a claim about "most" convex polyhedra.

Comment: I think the term I was seeking is [nowhere dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set): I think the $D_0$ polyhedra are nowhere dense.

Comment: You could add the question: “Is it true that classes $D_0$ and $D_2$ are nowhere-dense?” That would imply proportions of 0, 1, 0 for any reasonable measure.

Comment: It might also be worth rephrasing the classes as “$D_0$ if $d(P)$ is the distance between two non-vertices”, etc — this avoids referring to the endpoints of a distance, and clarifies how the classes might overlap.